# Not allowed to install or modify metadata via Apex

Tags: apex, metadata, exception, custom-metadata, metadata.operations

I know that this error is a hot topic and case for Salesforce but I tried to bypass this using some code workaround.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
// Upsert method call
   try {
        APTS_MetadataDeployCallback callback = new APTS_MetadataDeployCallback();
            
        // Call the helper class' method to bypass access issues & upsert metadata
        Id deploymentId = new BypassMetadataUpsert().upsertMetadata(mdContainer, callback);
        System.debug('DEPLOYMENT ID:::' + deploymentId);

        return true;
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.debug('Error while creating modifying custom metadata:::' + ex.getMessage());

        return false;
    }

// Inner class to bypass access issues
without sharing class BypassMetadataUpsert{
        Id upsertMetadata(Metadata.DeployContainer container, Metadata.DeployCallback callback){
            Id deploymentId = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(container, callback);
            return deploymentId;
        }
}
```

I've created an inner class using "without sharing" keyword to bypass access issues.

But still getting the same error which is **common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Not allowed to install or modify metadata via Apex**

Do you know any workaround that I can do on code level?

Comment: What was the error you were getting?

Comment: Hi Brian, I'm getting this error -> **common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Not allowed to install or modify metadata via Apex**

Comment: Does the user have the `Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions` and `Customize Application` permissions?

Comment: Since the target user group for that functionality is a standart user, can not give those permissions to the users.

Comment: Not even with permission sets?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, but since this looks like it is the only option to solve the issue, we're going to consider that option.

Comment: You could fire a platform event with the necessary payload and then configure the platform event subscriber to be a user w/ requisite permissions. This is my general strategy on delegating to a user with elevated permissions